# Create instance of generic class from type

Tags: c#, generics

I've got this class with a method that returns an object:

```
public class Deserializer<T>
{
    public static T FromJson(string json)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
    }   
}
```

And I've got a Type. How do I create an instance of the Deserializer class based on a this type? The following obviously doesn't work:

```
var type = typeOf(MyObject);
var foo = Deserializer<type>.FromJson(json);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could provide a non-generic version as well for consumers that don't know the type at compile-time (which is a good practice by the way when you are exposing an API):

```
public class Deserializer
{
    public static T FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
    }

    public static object FromJson(string json, Type type)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json, type);
    }
}
```

Now, consumers that know the type at compile-time:

```
Foo foo = Deserializer.FromJson<Foo>(json);
```

and consumers that don't know the type at compile-time:

```
Type type = ...
object instance = Deserializer.FromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: It works, but remember to reference the right version of System.Web.Extensions (.NET 4/4.5) where the Deserialize method takes type as an argument :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it, but it's not exactly optimal unless you absolutely must do it this way.  Go with one of the other answers if you can!

```
dynamic result = typeof(Deserializer<>).MakeGenericType(type)
    .InvokeMember("FromJson", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |
                              BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null,
                  new [] { json });
```

Comment: +1, Although you will need to create an instance to invoke this method.

Comment: I'm sure it works, but holy flying crackerjacks, Batman! That's not really the prettiest of answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Generic type parameters are statically bound (compile-time). You can't pass it a `System.Type` object.

For your simple example, You could (somewhat obviously) just use `MyObject`:

```
MyObject foo = Deserializer<MyObject>.FromJson(json);
```

If you could do this, what would the resultant type of `FromJson` be? How would you use that object?

```
Type t = ___;  // How do you get this?
??? foo = Deserializer<t>.FromJson(json);   // What datatype is foo?
```

What you're trying to do isn't a feature of a statically-typed language like C#. It's more of a dynamic language feature, like Python, where you just return whatever you want and do whatever you want to it.